# cart libraries in codeigniter not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

i have some problem in my libraries cart when i try to insert my product into the cart. could you help me.

here is my code link for product into the cart.

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cart/add"> 
        <span style="width: 70%;"><input type="submit" class="fa fa-cart-arrow-down btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" value="Add to Cart" <?php echo "$mati";?>/></span>
           <input type="hidden" name="id_books" value="<?php echo $row->id_books; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="id_category" value="<?php echo $row->id_category; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $row->title; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="images" value="<?php echo $row->images; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1"/>
    </form>
```

and this is cart controller

```
    class Cart extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library(array('cart'));
    session_start();
}


function index()
{
    $data['menu'] = 'cart';
    $this->load->view('v_cart', $data);
}

function add()
{
    $data = array(
        'id_books'      => $this->input->post('id_books'),
        'id_category'      => $this->input->post('id_category'),
        'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'),
        'price'   => $this->input->post('price'),
        'images'   => $this->input->post('images'),
        'title'    => $this->input->post('title'));
    $this->cart->insert($data);
    /*print_r($data);*/
    /*echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".base_url()."cart/'>";*/
    redirect('cart','refresh');
}
```

and this is cart view

```
    <?php if($cart = $this->cart->contents()):
                ?>
                <?php echo form_open('cart/update'); ?>
                    <table id="cart-table" class="table table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Action</th>

                                <th>Image</th>
                                <th>Product</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Quanity</th>
                                <th>Sub Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $i = 1; ?>
                            <?php foreach($cart as $item): /* $title = str_replace(' ', '-', $item['title']); ?>
                            <?php $price = $row['price']; $jumlah_desimal = "0"; $pemisah_desimal =""; $pemisah_ribuan =".";?>
                            <?php  /*echo form_hidden('rowid[]', $item['rowid']);*/ 
                             echo form_hidden($i.'[rowid]', $item['rowid']); ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="product-remove">
                                    <a class="remove" title="Remove this product" href="<?php echo base_url().'cart/delete/'.$item['rowid'];?>">×</a>
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <div class="media">
                                        <div class="relative">
                                            <a href="shop-single.html" title="">
                                                <img src="<?php echo base_url().$item['images'];?>" alt=""/>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- end media -->
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>books/detail/<?php echo $title;?>/<?php echo $item['id_category'];?>/<?php echo $item['id_books'];?> "><?php echo $item['title'];?></a>
                                </th>
                                <td>Rp. <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($item['price']); /*echo rupiah($item['price']); */?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo form_input(array('name' => $i.'[qty]', 'value' => $item['qty'], 'maxlength' => '3', 'class' => 'j')); ?> pcs
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Rp. <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($item['subtotal']);/*echo rupiah($item['subtotal']);*/ ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php $i++; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right!important;"><b>Total </b>(biaya buku)</td>
                                <td>
                                    Rp. <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <?php 
                    echo form_close(); 
                else:
                echo 'Sorry, Your Cart is empty';
                    endif;
                    ?>
```

the result always show

```
    Sorry, Your Cart is empty
```

where is the bug? anybody can help me :) 
thanks :)

Comment: Just use `$this->load->library('cart');` instead of this
 `$this->load->library(array('cart'));`

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter cart has predefined format:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/cart.html

```
$data = array(
               'id'      => 'sku_123ABC',
               'qty'     => 1,
               'price'   => 39.95,
               'name'    => 'T-Shirt',
               'options' => array('Size' => 'L', 'Color' => 'Red')
            );

$this->cart->insert($data);
```

So you code will be,

```
function add()
{
    $data = array(
        'id'=>someID,
        'name'=>SomeName,
        'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'),
        'price'   => $this->input->post('price'),
        'options' =>array('id_books'=> $this->input->post('id_books'),'id_category'=> $this->input->post('id_category'),'images'   => $this->input->post('images'),'title'    => $this->input->post('title'));

    $this->cart->insert($data);
    /*print_r($data);*/
    /*echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=".base_url()."cart/'>";*/
    redirect('cart','refresh');
}
```